# Comparing value of int.TryParse result

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, substring, tryparse

I feel kind of silly asking this because either I'm missing something increidbly easy or not understanding the tryParse function at all.

In laymans terms, what I want to do in the following code is have the code loop through all of the columns in a datagridview.  If the last 2 characters of the column name are numeric, I then want to compare the numeric value of the last 2 characters (using int.TryParse) to another variable.  essentially I want to make all of my columns read only excpet for those columns where the last 2 digits can be converted to an integer and that integer is greater than the vairable I'm comparing to.

My code below is probably a little mundane as I'm trying to go through step by step setting variables before the int_tryParse but I can fix that later.

C#, VS2008:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in grd1.Columns)
                {
                    string myCol = col.Name;
                    int myColLength = col.Name.Length;
                    string myColMonth = myCol.Substring(myColLength - 2);
                    if (int.TryParse(myColMonth, out myColMonth) <= myMostRecentActualMonth)
                    {
                        col.ReadOnly = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        col.ReadOnly = false;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TryParse` method returns a `Boolean` value indicating if the parse was successful or not.  If so, it sets the output parameter to the parsed value.

So what you'll want is something like:

```
int parsedMonth; // This will get set if myColMonth is a valid integer
if (int.TryParse(myColMonth, out parsedMonth) && parsedMonth <= myMostRecentActualMonth)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Essentially I came up with a similar solution, because you know of course after 40 minutes of working on it I figured it out 10 minutes after I posted it (sigh)

Comment: @RyanWard - Actually a huge reason why I post questions on StackOverflow is because it guarantees I will figure it out on my own 30 seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

`int.TryParse` has a return type of bool:

Try going from here:

```
       foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in grd1.Columns)
        {
            string myCol = col.Name;
            int myColLength = col.Name.Length;
            string myColMonth = myCol.Substring(myColLength - 2);
            int myIntColMonth;
            if (int.TryParse(myColMonth, out myIntColMonth) 
                && myIntColMonth <= myMostRecentActualMonth)
            {
                col.ReadOnly = true;
            }
            else
            {
                col.ReadOnly = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your code like this, first you need another `int` value to which you should store your parsed value, then check if that value is lower than `myMostRecentActualMonth`

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in grd1.Columns)
{
    string myCol = col.Name;
    int myColLength = col.Name.Length;
    string myColMonth = myCol.Substring(myColLength - 2);
    int myColMonthIntValue = int.MaxValue;
    if (int.TryParse(myColMonth, out myColMonthIntValue) && myColMonthIntValue <= myMostRecentActualMonth)
    {
        col.ReadOnly = true;
    }
    else
    {
        col.ReadOnly = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TryParse` returns a bool indicating whether or not the conversion was successful. You don't want to compare the result of `TryParse` (what you're doing) you instead want to compare with the variable you're passing into it.

So;
     if (int.TryParse(myColMonth, out myColMonth) <= myMostRecentActualMonth)

needs to become;

```
 if (int.TryParse(myColMonth, out myColMonth)
    if ( myColMonth <= myMostRecentActualMonth)
```

First checking that you parsed out an int, then doing the compare.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in grd1.Columns)
     {
         string myCol = col.Name;
         int myColLength = col.Name.Length;
         string myColMonth = myCol.Substring(myColLength - 2);
         int myColMonthInt = 0;
         if (int.TryParse(myColMonth, out myColMonthInt)) 
         {  
             if (myColMonthInt <= myMostRecentActualMonth)
             {
                 col.ReadOnly = true;
             }
             else
             {
                 col.ReadOnly = false;
             }
         } 
         else 
         {
             // what do you want to do is last two chars can't be converted to int?
             col.ReadOnly = true;
         }
     }
```